# C++ project in VS2019 not outputting exe

Tags: c++, compilation, output

I am building a C++ project in Visual Studio 2019 which is not outputting an executable.

1. In Configuration Properties -> General -> Configuration Type, I have it set to Application (.exe) for all configurations, all platforms
2. In Configuration Properties -> General -> Output Directory is set the same for all configurations, all platforms
3. In Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General, the Output File is set and the same for all configurations, all platforms
4. In the browser window, I choose Build -> Rebuild Solution and I see the following output: `project.vcxproj -> C:\Users\name\source\repos\project\x64\Debug\project.exe` but that file does not exist
5. Same as 4. but with release version, still doesn't work
6. Same as 4. and 5., except I choose Build -> Rebuild ProjectName, still nothing

What's in the output folder?

- project.obj
- project.log
- vc142.pdb
- log files

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you execute your code from within VS? Any chance that your antivirus silently nuked it?

Comment: No idea, but my advice would be to create a new project (console application type) and don't tinker with anything. It's not necessary to adjust all those settings, they have reasonable default values.

Comment: @BessieTheCow Yes, it runs just fine with any configuration within VS... I'll try disabling my antivirus and see if the file magically comes back.

Comment: If you can run your code then there must be an executable file somewhere. Try searching for it in the solution folder.

Comment: @BessieTheCow Very confused... Disabled antivirus and still nothing. I see when I run the program in VS the first line is `'project.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\name\source\repos\project\x64\Release\project.exe'. Symbols loaded.` but even while the program is running, that file does not exist. I also have `Show Hidden Files` enabled but still nothing.